# sulu cms set up multi port website

Tags: symfony, sulu

How can i set up multi portal website in sulu cms?

Example: I will have one admin panel from that i will manage content of site like

a.com, b.com, c.com...

I try by make copy of file 
app/Resources/webspaces/example.com.xml
and make file lilke app/Resources/webspaces/one.com.xml

And in example.com.xml i also add another portal tag in portals but had no luck...

but in admin panel left side i see just one site example.com

How can i do that? Is there any documentation? Any link?
Thanks!

Comment: You might be able to find out more if you try searching about 'multiple domains' instead of 'portals'.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple portals within the same webspace are not visible in the Administration UI, what you want are multiple webspaces. Just create a second XML file as described in our [documentation](http://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/book/webspaces.html), and make sure you have different URLs setup and both webspaces have a different value in their `key` tag. Afterwards you have to execute the `bin/console sulu:document:init` command once more to initialize some nodes.

Maybe also check the logs in `var/logs` for any errors and warnings, because if you have an error in your webspace configuration file, the new webspace will not show up in the admin UI.

Another thing that could go wrong is that you are missing the permissions to see the new webspace (that usually happens when you create a new webspace after you've executed the command mentioned above). In that case you have to navigate to Settings -> User roles -> Your userrole, and add the missing permissions in the shown matrix.

Comment: Having unique `<url>` values for every webspace.xml is actually super important - otherwise quite some strange issues are happening.